# Looking for a standard Java method (or, UDF if necessary) to check if one hashset is a subset of another

Tags: java

It should return true if one HashSet A is a subset of another HashSet B, false otherwise.

Comment: `containsAll` method will give you the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if it has to be a strict subset or it can be equal.

```
Set a = ...
Set b = ...
```

If you can use containsAll

```
return b.containsAll(a);
```

or if it has to be a strict subset

```
return b.size() > a.size() && b.containsAll(a);
```

or you can

```
Set tmp = new HashSet(a);
tmp.removeAll(b);
return tmp.isEmpty();
```

Comment: It wastes memory by creating a new HashSet just for removal, though.

Comment: @nhahtdh I agree, but sometimes homework doesn't take the simplest option. ;)

Answer (score 3):

[`Set.containsAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#containsAll%28java.util.Collection%29) does what you want:

> Returns true if this set contains all of the elements of the specified collection. If the specified collection is also a set, this method returns true if it is a subset of this set.

Answer (score 2):

Set.containsAll method should do the job:

```
B.containsAll(A)
```